# Wordpress moving entire site to different folder / changing, updating permalinks in MySQL db etc

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp-pro

Higuys I’m just getting into word press development.

I am trying to make an exact backup of a wordpress site from my local MAMP pro environment and get it running again at another folder.

I successfully reinstalled the site, and its up and going but unfortunatley all of my permalinks are still pointing to the old websiite, I can’t even go to http://mynewsite:8888/wp-admin because that url redirects to http://myoldsite:8888/wp-admin (the old site)

Heres what I have done

1. copied and pasted all of the wp-directory contents to the new location
2. copied/exported my existing wp website database SQL
3. created a new database/name
4. imported the backedup SQL into my new database
5. made a new host in MAMP PRO that points to my new sites directory
6. updated wp-config in new site to point to my new database/name
7. run the new site in the browser

From what I read here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Its says to download

Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

and run it to replace the old permalink url with the new one

but when I run this script (after setting up a host for it in MAMP) from http://searchreplacescript:8888 and running it in the browser the page loads with all of its options but I get in a red box under the database tab

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

what do I need to change this to to get it to connect to MySQL??? (MySQL is definitely running, I can go to myPHP admin etc).
I’m just running default MAMP Pro.

Any help would be great, I also tried the plugin “duplicator” I was able to duplicate the site but unfortunatley could not extract the site even though the plugin told me everything was a success

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried emptying the content of your .htaccess at the root of your wordpress site? Don't delete it, just empty it.

One this is done, go to yourwebsite/wp-admin, general, make sure the new address is correct and click save.
Go to permalinks, select the correct one and save again. This will recreate your .htaccess.
Then go to your theme settings (if any), and click save.

FYI, I invested in BackupBuddy plugin to avoid having to do all the steps you've done and it's a great time saver.

Ps: in your MAMP, make sure "Rewrite module" is ticked in Apache config (I had a similar problem with UwAmp).

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @seiferflo I tried clearing out the .htaccess file like you suggested but unfortuantley it did nothing, I cleared it restarted MAMP and refreshed my browser then went to 
http://mynewsite:8888/wp-admin 
but as soon as I hit enter here it redirects straight to 
http://myoldsite:8888/wp-admin

Comment: I edited the database manually in phpmyadmin wp_options table change the site URL there, and I was able to to then access the backend of the site. Also also updated teh home field, but the GUID field in the wp_posts table still shows the old URL but for whatever reason the site runs fine like this. Isn't GUID wp_posts important?

Comment: Yes it is. 
Best way to edit the database like this is using this: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
Download it, put it at the root of your wordpress website in a folder called searchdb. Launch it: mynewsite/searchdb, then fill "replace" and "'with", and start with dry run. It won't write anything to the db but will make sure all your entries are correct. When you're sure, just use a live run. Make sure you made a backup of your db before end.